Movie where boy creates a portal to other dimension in garage
lately I watched a movie half asleep and can't remember the name; here is the plot:
A boy builds a device in his garage and to finish it he needs a part of a car, he goes to a car-dump and while picking up the part he meets another boy with whom he goes back to his garage and tells him it's a teleportation device. He starts the device and all the electricity goes blank in seconds and the toy he placed on the device vanished. After that there is a time-jump and he's in a science competition (highschool?) where he demonstrates a new version of his device and a company finds him and tells him his device teleports to another dimension, not only to Earth
Language: I only know the dub of my country (German); should be a rather new movie judging by the camera quality.

Approximate year of release? Country\language? Any other details you might remember?

Language i only know the dub of my country (german), should be a rather new movie judging by the camera quality, after that there is a time-jump and he´s in a science competition (highschool?) where he demonstrates a new version of his device and a company finds him and tells him his device teleports to another dimension not only to earth

If this is your question, please follow the contact us link at the bottom to ask that your accounts be merged. If this is not your question, please ask a new one using the "ask question" button. We are a Q&A site, not a forum, so posting clarifications as an answer is not acceptable practice here. Please, do be extremely descriptive in your new question as our rules for ID questions are very strict.

I wonder if you could be referencing "My Science Project" (1985).
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089652/
IMDb Storyline:

Michael and Ellie break into a military junkyard to find a science project for Michael's class, and discover a strange glowing orb which absorbs electricity. When the orb begins to blend past, present, and future, its up to Michael and Ellie to stop the orb and save mankind. 


Thank you for assisting the community. Can you please also add what is it about this movie that fits the details in the question (and what doesn't fit)? I hope you enjoy participating.

It's called Shadows on the Wall. The description doesn't really say anything but the movie is exactly how you described it:

Three college students struggle to create a device capable of reaching
  beyond the boundaries of the known universe. Unfortunately for them,
  they succeed...

